# Lat Long to XY coordinates

Tags: java, android, maps

I'm trying to draw a point on a custom map using gps coordinates. I am looking for a way to convert a gps coordinate to a pixel value I could draw on the map. I'm working in android but  help would be appreciated just to figure out the logic. The image is 3000 x 2102 and I have a gps coordinate of lat 45.8932 long -59.98573.  I've tried a few examples but I haven't been able to get it to work, the issue i seem to be having is the numbers I am dealing with is that the numbers are too small to make any movement on the map.

Comment: What is your map of?  What's in those 3000x2102 - the whole world or 2 city blocks?

Comment: What projection does your map use?

Comment: what's wrong with a linear interpolation is the area is so small ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to answer your question the way it is.  To determine the coordinates you need to have GPS coordinates of the corners of the image.  For example, if your image has gps coordinates of (lat = 50, lon = 0) - for the top left corner and (lat = 0, lon = 50) for bottom right corner, then the point you specified is not on that image at all.  Provided the point is within the image, then it's a matter of simple math to figure out where your GPS point falls on the map image.  Of course, you may need to take into account the fact that the map may not be linear, especially as you approach poles.

Comment: A linear approach will only work for small areas like a city.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I know, that's why I said in my answer _Of course, you may need to take into account the fact that the map may not be linear_

Comment: I have the bounds, and also this area is quite small. TopLeft: 45.8936667, -59.98375 TopRight: 45.8906833, -59.98375 BottomLeft:  45.8936668, -59.9889, bottom right: 45.89068333, -59.9889.  I'm really confused about the math involved.